# How to access a subset of keys among the labels in the JSON object returned by docker/metadata-action Github action

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, github-actions, cicd

I'm trying to combine [docker/metadata-action](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action) and
[docker/build-push-action](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action) in a Github Actions workflow file according to the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images) to publish a Docker image.

The problem that I'm having is that I want to only select a subset of labels returned by `metadata-action` as the labels to be applied to the final Docker image.

This is how my workflow looks like

```
name: Build Docker Image and Publish to Registry

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

permissions:
  contents: read
  packages: write

env:
  DOCKER_REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build-and-publish-docker-image:
    name: Build and publish the Docker image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Login to Docker registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}/${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME }}
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=sha,event=workflow_dispatch

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

This works, except I want to limit the set of labels that will be applied to the final Docker image to only `org.opencontainers.image.created` and `org.opencontainers.image.revision` and leave the rest to the default ones set in the `Dockerfile`.

I tried the following, but it failed because I guess there is a syntax error.

```
          labels: |
            org.opencontainers.image.created=${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels."org.opencontainers.image.created" }}
            org.opencontainers.image.revision=${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels."org.opencontainers.image.revision" }}
```

According to the workflow logs, the JSON output of `metadata-action` looks like this:

```
{
  "tags": [
    "ghcr.io/user/repo:main",
    "ghcr.io/user/repo:sha-22afbbc"
  ],
  "labels": {
    "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2023-06-14T11:03:48.368Z",
    "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Repo",
    "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "",
    "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "22afbbca4957b358f0bbfba9936e42bfac08d3b3",
    "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/user/repo",
    "org.opencontainers.image.title": "repo",
    "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/user/repo",
    "org.opencontainers.image.version": "main"
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @Operator 's answer works, I found out that there is a cleaner way to achieve this:

```
  labels: |
    org.opencontainers.image.created=${{ fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).labels['org.opencontainers.image.created'] }}
    org.opencontainers.image.revision=${{ fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).labels['org.opencontainers.image.revision'] }}
    org.opencontainers.image.version=${{ fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).labels['org.opencontainers.image.version'] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
- name: Set labels
  id: labels
  run: |
    echo "image-created=$(echo '${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}' | jq -r '.labels."org.opencontainers.image.created"')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    echo "image-revision=$(echo '${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}' | jq -r '.labels."org.opencontainers.image.revision"')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

- name: Build and push
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
  with:
    context: .
    file: ./Dockerfile
    tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
    labels: |
      ${{ steps.labels.outputs.image-created }}
      ${{ steps.labels.outputs.image-revision }}
```

In case the runner doesn't have `jq` command you can add a command to install it in the beginning of the set labels step, something like `sudo apt install -y jq` or whichever that suits your needs, refer to: https://jqlang.github.io/jq/download/.

PS: Edited to add a slight syntax fix.